# Can I add a Git link types(Branch, commit etc.)to my TFS(AZURE) WorkItems from Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

## Integration problems between VS and TFS

My Team and Me faced a very confusing problem.
We have changed our Version Control System from TVSC to Git.
But we're still using Tfs as Project Managment tool, so our git project is hosted in Tfs.
The problem is that we can not add git link types from IDE(Visual Studio). So we have to use Web UI to do that.

[Link types in VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQaNO.png)

[Link types in Azure DevOps Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TuEx.png)

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you wanting to add links to work items in a commit message, or something else?

Comment: We discovered that there is an option to add commits to the workitems when we're pushing them to the server by using #WORK_ITEM_NUMBER. But we want to add Branch link type within VS. Whithout using web ui.

Comment: The work item management experience in Visual Studio is largely deprecated. Use the web UI.

Comment: Yes, but it is more then enough for developers. So is there some way to solve it?

Comment: @DavidNaik No. It's deprecated, which means it isn't receiving updates anymore. It doesn't support what you want to do and almost certainly never will. The solution is to use the modern replacement, which is the web UI.

Comment: We created a branch policy preventing anyone from checking directly into Master.   We make everyone create a branch for there changes and create a pull request to get the changes into master.  You can assign TFS items to pull requests

Comment: @DaielMann I know that it's deprecated. But mb there is a way to work mostly with VS. That's what I'm asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I add a Git link types(Branch, commit etc.)to my TFS(AZURE) WorkItems from Visual Studio?

Sorry for any inconvenience.

This behavior is by designed and is not a issue. There is no way to fix it at present.

Just as Daniel said:

> **The work item management experience in Visual Studio is largely deprecated.**

Besides, the New Development section on work items is a follow-up newly developed feature:

[Linking Work Items to Git Branches, Commits, and Pull Requests](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/linking-work-items-to-git-branches-commits-and-pull-requests/)

Since MS is ready to deprecate work item management in Visual Studio, MS has not implemented this feature on Visual Studio, nor does it intend to implement it. That is reason why you see this feature on the web UI, but only see add related link workitem not the Branch, commit etc.

If it important to you, you could add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions. But it may not be accepted by MS.

[image]

Hope this helps.